# Is there any AWS service which can make API gateway wait until it receives data from another AWS service (apart from Lambda)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

## What I want

[image]

1. Lambda function is triggered when file is uploaded to bucket.
2. Lambda performs some processing on data and adds the same to DynamoDB.
3. After some time an API call is made to GET the data.

## what I tried

1. DynamoDB behind API gateway: No data if request is prematurely made.
2. The lambda behind S3 is instead triggered when API gateway is called: I want processing to start immediately after file upload.

## What's the issue

I want to make use of the time gap between the two calls by starting processing immediately. But if second request is prematurely made then no data will be returned. I can add a second Lambda which can cause API gateway to hold up till data is ready (29 second timeout of API gateway). But is there any tailor made service for this case, that can make API gateway wait (Lambda alternative for 29 second hold)?

Comment: Probably not, apigateway has a timeout of 29 seconds. Anything after that fails. The client would need to retry the request of no data is returned.

Comment: Please note that the AWS API Gateway has a max timeout of 29 seconds.

Comment: 29 second timeout fits my use case. I just don't want an instant not found response. This happens when DynamoDB is proxied with API gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such service and there is good reason for that

API Gateway do actually wait until DynamoDB respond *but DynamoDB respond immediately* with a not found result. Therefore the logic you are asking for would be more like

```
API Gateway should poll DynamoDB continously until 29 seconds or a result is found
```

This is not natively supported but you can do as you suggested (use a Lambda to poll continously until you get your result )

Or even simpler: Let the client call API Gateway continously until the result is found